# Fix a header element's position above another element

Tags: html, css, positioning

I am trying to position the header above my form and I want it to move with the form. Instead, it moves behind the form when the screen is being zoomed in and towards the very top when it is being zoomed out, which creates a big gap in between the two. I am copy-pasting both of the codes from html and CSS.

My background picture is set to: `position:fixed;` The form is `position:absolute`; And the header `position: relative`.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Please avoid code screenshots.  It's more useful if code is entered as text.

Comment: I see. I'm sorry. I don't know the rules yet.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the css for the `header` is not set as `position:fixed;` if you want the header to scroll with the form. Hope this helps! If you have any other questions feel free to ask. Heres updated code:

```html
.header {
     position:static;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply!! I am trying to figure out this portal. How do I paste my code (so it is not in one paragraph), since snapshots are not recommendable?

Comment: It's not that snapshots aren't recommended. It's that your post should be clear without them as well. You can post images if that helps, but you should also paste the code itself. You can create blocks of code by surrounding text in triple backticks (this character `). For example, backtickbacktickbacktickYOURCODEbacktickbacktickbacktick.